# Early stop using validation callback

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I'm trying to callback with validation (val_loss) but validation is not taking place. this warning is shown "WARNING:tensorflow:Early stopping conditioned on metric `val_loss` which is not available. Available metrics are: loss,accuracy"

```
`check=callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_accuracy', mode='auto',patience=2,verbose=1)
 
 history = model.fit(train_dataset,
                          steps_per_epoch=163,
                          epochs=10,
                          validation_data=val_dataset,
                          validation_steps=624,
                          callbacks = [check])`
```

Comment: Did you try skipping the validation_steps parameter?
What is the length/size of your data?
Seems to me that your validation_steps parameter might be higher than the actual size of the validation data that you have available(val_dataset, as you defined it)

Comment: Can you add your model.compile statement? And the complete code to make it possible to reproduce the error.

Comment: thanks, @IvanPetrovicMarkovic I removed validation_steps and it worked. though i calculated validation_steps as len/size only.

Answer (score 2):

Providing the solution here (Answer Section) even though it is present in the Comments Section **for the benefit of the Community**.

The above code which comprises `Early Stopping` and `model.fit` works fine if we remove the argument, **`validation_steps`**.

Working code is shown below:

```
check=callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_accuracy', mode='auto',patience=2,verbose=1)
 

history = model.fit(train_dataset,
                              steps_per_epoch=163,
                              epochs=10,
                              validation_data=val_dataset,
                              callbacks = [check])
```

The reason can be understood from the [Tensorflow Documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit) corresponding to the argument, `validation_steps` as shown below:

> **validation_steps:** Only relevant if validation_data is provided and is a tf.data dataset. Total number of steps (batches of samples) to
> draw before stopping when performing validation at the end of every
> epoch. If 'validation_steps' is None, validation will run until the
> validation_data dataset is exhausted. In the case of an infinitely
> repeated dataset, it will run into an infinite loop. If
> 'validation_steps' is specified and only part of the dataset will be
> consumed, the evaluation will start from the beginning of the dataset
> at each epoch. This ensures that the same validation samples are used
> every time.